# PHP variables in leafletjs javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm wanting to dynamically draw a leafletjs map on a page using latitude and longitude variables stored in a Wordpress database.  I'm so close!

In my functions.php I've got

```
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts","my_scripts_loader");


function my_scripts_loader(){
    $data = array('lat' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'latitude_metric' ),
                'long' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'longitude_metric' ));

   wp_enqueue_script( 'windfarm', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/windfarm.js', array(jquery), '', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'windfarm', 'php_data', $data );

}
```

which pulls the values I need.

It's the next stage that I'm falling over with.

The head of my windfarm.js file is

```
var lat = "php_data.lat";
var long = "php_data.long";
var mymap = L.map('location').setView([lat, long], 9);
```

This isn't working!  I get this in the console.

```
 [Error] Error: Invalid LatLng object: (php_data.lat, php_data.long)
```

As I say I know I'm close as

```
alert(php_data.lat);
alert(php_data.long);
```

does the job with a couple of pop ups.

How do I take these lat and long values and use them in the **var mymap** line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it if anyone else wants to know...  (we all begin at the beginning)

var lat = parseFloat(php_data.lat);
var long = parseFloat(php_data.long);